# Visiting producer-consumer design pattern

Tags: design-patterns, producer-consumer

What is producer consumer design pattern? Code example, prefarably  in C++ would be helpfull. I couldn't find it in gang of four book nor via quick google search.

Comment: Where did you come across that particular term/phrasing? What makes you want to understand/use it? Maybe the context can help answering. If a quick search did not help, mabye do an intensive search, e.g. look for the well known producer consumer pattern (many search hits on that...) and read the articles, whether they mention visiting.

Comment: We use it in work. But I need to learn it on my own if possible. And documentation barely states it is pattern that use ideas both from visitor pattern and producer consumer.

Comment: Isn't that the answer you are looking for? It is not a single pattern "visiting producer-consumer". You are looking at code which applies two separate patterns.

Comment: It is single pattern and I do not understand what it precisly does and how it does it.

Comment: You failed to find a description of the single pattern. So did I. Your documentation seems quite clear that it is two separate patterns. Why do you insist that it must be a single pattern? it is one of the basic ideas of design patterns that they can be combined to solve problems. They play well with each other.

Comment: Thank you, you right. Found some example: //softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/311038/what-is-an-appropriate-pattern-for-handling-a-queue-of-network-events-in-c

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. The question you have posted does not fall in the scope of questions discussed here. Please refer to the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to see what kind of questions you can ask here. Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking at something which uses a combination of two known design patterns, not a single design pattern "visiting producer-consumer".
Your documentation (judging from your description in comments) seems quite clear on this.
Design patterns are meant to be used in combination, their definition is usually flexible (i.e. no code specified).
You can probably read up on both mentioned patterns and identify the code parts which implement them.

Answer (score 0):

Yunnosh thank you, you right that those are two patterns used together. 
Found following link with good example: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/311038/what-is-an-appropriate-pattern-for-handling-a-queue-of-network-events-in-c